# How to delete raster dataset from sde base programmatically

Tags: arcobjects, raster, c#, data, enterprise-geodatabase

I use sde database, registered with ArcGis Server 10.1. Sde connection is direct. Database container is postgres.

There is a raster dataset in this sde base. I can open this sde database

```
    private IWorkspace ArcSdeWorkspaceFromFile(String connectionFile)
    {
        Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(
            "esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory");
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance
            (factoryType);
        return workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(connectionFile, 0);
    }
```

and raster dataset.
I can also add some data to this registered raster dataset.

```
    private void OpenRasterDataset()
    {
        IRasterWorkspaceEx temp = (IRasterWorkspaceEx)fgdbWorkspace;
        rasterDataset = temp.OpenRasterDataset(SdeParameters.rdName);
    }
```

But I don't know how to delete (or clear - it is the best way) this raster dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to query interface to [IDatatset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000147000000), then call the delete method.

```
((IDataset)rasterDataset).Delete();
```